# Is it possible to somehow generate @property php doc for protected/private fields in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I would like to ask you if it is possible to generate @property phpdoc for class based on protected/private fields in PHPStorm. Here is an example:

Before:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Abc
{
    use MagicAccessors;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $a;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $b;
    ...
```

After:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @property string $a
 * @property string $b
 */
class Abc
{
    use MagicAccessors;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $a;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $b;
    ...
```

My point is that I would like to generate sometimes property phpdocs automatically because sometimes I use magic accessors. Is it clear?:)

Thank you!